# I'm getting an weird output in php on printing an url stored in a string variable

Tags: php, curl

I'm supposed to perform the curl operation and unfortunately the request is keep on sending without any response been returned. While investigating this i got know the url string is in trouble. Im supposed to open 'http://api.ikarthick.in' instead i could able to 'http: //api.ikarthick.in' which has a white space between : & // . Kindly check the below code.

```
<?php
    $url = "http://api.ikarthick.in"; //as it is public in stackoverflow i've truncated the exact url

    print($url);
    return; //used this return only while investigating the issue which that i got see whats in $url

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    print($response);
?>
```

For this the output i see on my Postman as mentioned below,

```
http: //api.ikarthick.in
```

Also when click `//api.ikarthick.in` on the POSTMAN response screen, i got to see `http://localhost//ikarthick.in` being opened in the new tab of POSTMAN. I tried running the same on webbrowser and got the expected output.

But problem is, i can't make curl operation with the above url. Could anyone help me to fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible that there is some invisible whitespace character contained within the string for whatever reason. I would recommend deleting the entire `http://` portion of the url and then re-typing it manually to see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: Why you put an empty space between http:// and the domain?

Comment: Thanks @B.Fleming for you're response. I've tried that in IDE and doesn't helps and  hanshenrik 's answer below helped me.

Answer (score 0):

probably an invisible whitespace in the code which your IDE is not good at handling.

open the source code in a hex editor and remove the whitespace there. if you're on Windows, [HxD Hex Editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) is an excellent choice, as for Linux, [Bless Hex Editor](https://github.com/afrantzis/bless) is decent.

Comment: Thanks alot Hans Henrik Bergan ! This really worked out. If possible can you please suggest me a good IDE. Currently im using Visual Studio on my MacOS ?

Comment: @KarthickTamilselvan not sure if you're talking about `Visual Studio` or `Visual Studio Code` (2 different IDE's with very similar name, but i thought only the latter actually supported Mac), but both of those are decent IDE's anyway.. i do most of my PHP work in Eclipse, but i'm not convinced Eclipse would do a better job than Visual Studio about weird whitespaces

Comment: Yeah, @hanshenrik you're right got confused with the similar names. I'm using Visual Studio Code presently let me give a try with Eclipse as well. Cheers!